# How to add single or double quote in every email address

Tags: php, mysql, regex

How do i add single or double quote in every email add sample

after implode my email should be look like this

```
(red@yahoo.com, blue@yahoo.com, yellow@yahoo.com, white@yahoo.com)
```

convert that array string to:

```
('red@yahoo.com', 'blue@yahoo.com', 'yellow@yahoo.com', 'white@yahoo.com')
```

or

```
("red@yahoo.com", "blue@yahoo.com", "yellow@yahoo.com", "white@yahoo.com")



    $num = count($email);
   for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
    $result = do_post_request("http://api.myapi.com/api/IsActiveAccount?email=".  $email[$i], null);
    $status = str_replace('{"result":', "", $result);
    $status = str_replace('}', "", $status);
    $value_email[] = $email[$i] ;
    $value_status[] = $status ;
}
  $val_email = implode(',',$value_email);
  $value_status = implode(',',$value_status);

  define ("VERIFY_EMAIL_UPDATE_SENT", " UPDATE `accounts` SET sent = 1 WHERE email IN (".$val_email.") AND active <> 1");
  $db->query(VERIFY_EMAIL_UPDATE_SENT);
  echo 'Done'; 

  Error because ---->email IN (red@yahoo.com, blue@yahoo.com, yellow@yahoo.com, white@yahoo.com)
```

Comment: post some code Man How can I understand in which form you are receiving this

Comment: Could you add the code to your question?

Comment: the originating string looks like...? And you've already tried ...?

Comment: You seem to be defining a constant that contains your SQL query - that's a very unusual way of doing it. Is there a reason why a simple variable won't work?

Comment: @andrewsi no the way i implode my array when i follow Joseph Silber it gives me the correct syntax thanks anyway

Comment: @ArkNet - you've missed my point. I'm wondering why your SQL is being set as a constant, rather than as a variable. Both methods will work, but I don't think I've ever seen a constant used before, so I was wondering if there was a reason for it.

Comment: I need to transfer that later on, the constant to another page and every time i need to used it, i just include/call

Comment: @ArkNet - that's fair enough - I've not seen it done that way before, but if it's working.... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with that string:

```
$result = '("' . implode('", "', $emails) . '")';
```

Here's a demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/3suUci

Comment: You probably want quotes on the outside, too. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie no just like this one ("red@yahoo.com", "blue@yahoo.com", "yellow@yahoo.com", "white@yahoo.com")

Comment: the error part is in mysql statement this one UPDATE `accounts` SET sent = 1 WHERE email IN (".$val_email.") AND active <> 1 because of the email format. it should be "email" or 'email'